# does anyone have a solution for me to access a subfolder of my application behind nginx proxy?

Tags: nginx

I have two servers with different IP addresses:

- Tomcat serving my webapp `https://app1.domain.com` (centos6)
- Nginx acting as waf via `https://nginx.domain.com` (centos7)

Nginx is running on port 443, and I'm using it to reverse proxy my webapp this way:

```
location /app1/ {
    rewrite ^/app1(.*) /$1 break; 
    proxy_pass https://app1.domain.com/;
}
```

This way, I normally access my webapp via nginx through `https://nginx.domain.com/app1/`.

Secondly, in the `ROOT` folder of my webapp, I installed the birt-viewer application in the `ROOT/birt-viewer` folder. I normally access the birt-viewer application when I use the link `https://app1.domain.com/birt-viewer`.

However, I don't normally access the birt application when I use the link `https:// nginx.domain.com/app1/birt-viewer`. When I copy for example the link

```
/birt-viewer/Task.jsp?__report=Recare.rpgn&sample=my+parameter&__sessionId=2026
```

and I paste it after the link `https://nginx.domain.com/app1` to obtain the final link

```
https://nginx.domain.com/app1/birt-viewer/Task.jsp?__report=Recare.rpgn&sample=my+parameter&__sessionId=2026
```

I access the birt-viewer application but I lose settings such as cookies and sessions.

You understand that to access my webapp via nginx I have to do it manually; the disadvantage is the loss of cookies, sessions and other parameters.
Yet access should be done automatically without problems.

This is my nginx config:

```
user nginxxxx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log /var/log/error.log warn;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
#    include mime.types;
    include /opt/nginx/conf/mime.types;    
    include /opt/nginx/conf/naxsi_core.rules;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /var/log/access.log main;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;

    server {
         listen 443 ssl;
        server_name nginx.domain.com;
    access_log on ;
        access_log /var/log/access.log main;
    error_log on ;
        error_log /var/log/error.log warn;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/m.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/cs.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    error_page 403 /403_error.html;
        location = /403_error.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/htmml;
            internal;
        }

    error_page 404 /404_error.html;
        location = /404_error.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            internal;
        }


 location /app1/
         {
rewrite ^/app1(.*) /$1 break;
proxy_connect_timeout 60000;
proxy_send_timeout 60000;
proxy_read_timeout 60000;
send_timeout 60000;
proxy_pass https://app1.domain.com/;
   }

location /app1/birt-viewer/ {
    rewrite ^/app1/folder1(.*) /$1 break; 
    proxy_pass https:// app1.domain.com/birt-viewer/;
}

           }

}
```

I also realize that once my webapp behind nginx, some urls are not up to date and still keep the old access.

So my concern is to access the birt-viewer application automatically (not manually) through nginx via `https://nginx.domain.com/app1/birt-viewer`

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Comment: Errata! Errata
I meant that I am unable to access files in these folders through **nginx.domain.com/app1/folder1** or **nginx.domain.com/app1/folder2**; I get the 404 error

does anyone have a solution for me to access a subfolder of my application behind nginx proxy?

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: Mister Djdomi Thank you for your comments; I just edited the question with more details.

Comment: the showb configuration does not reflect the current used state, are you obfuscated something? please show and share the correct configuration. nginx -T helps you

Comment: Mister Djdomi Once again Thank you for your comments; I just edited the question with the whole nginx config.